# Product of block matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, block-matrices

Let $A$ be a $(n\times k)$-matrix, $B$ a $(n\times d)$-matrix and $M=[A \quad B]$ the block matrix (or the augmented matrix).
Doing the calculations, I obtained that
$$M'M=
\left ( \begin{array}{cc}
A'A & A'B\\
B'A & B'B
\end{array}\right ),
$$
where $'$ stands for transposition.

Do you have a good justification for this result rather than observe it by brute force?

Comment: So you're asking why is $M^TM$ equal to that (i assumed your ' was referring to transpose)

Comment: yes. its the transpose

Comment: And what's exactly the question? The calculations give that result

Comment: @AlejandroBergasaAlonso I asked for arguments that use more general linear algebra results , "rather than observe it by brute force."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Block-matrix multiplication is a very useful tool which, unfortunately, is rarely explained well.  Here's the way I think about it.

Recall that if we choose a basis for a vector space $V$, any linear transformation has an associated matrix (whose entries are numbers) with respect to this choice of basis. Similarly, if we break a vector space into a direct sum $V = V_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus V_n$, then a block matrix specifies that transformation with respect to this decomposition into a direct sum.

Definitions of a direct sum of vector spaces vary, but I mean the following. We say that $V = V_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus V_n$ ($V$ is the direct sum of $V_1,\dots,V_n$) if $V$ is the vector space whose elements are the column-vectors
$$
v = (v_1,\dots,v_n)  = \pmatrix{v_1 \\ \hline v_2 \\ \hline \vdots \\ \hline v_n}, \quad v_i \in V_i, \ i = 1,\dots,n.
$$
The horizontal lines in the second version are simply a notational convenience, used to emphasize the separation between the cells of our column vector. It will often be convenient to refer to an element of the form $v = (0,\dots,0,v,0,\dots,0)$. To that end, we will use the notation $v \otimes e_i:= (0,\dots,0,v,0,\dots,0)$, where $i$ is the index of the non-zero entry. So, we could write
$$
(v_1,\dots,v_n) = v_1 \otimes e_1 + v_2 \otimes e_2 + \cdots + v_n \otimes e_n.
$$
(this notation is ultimately motivated by the definition of the tensor product, but explaining this is not necessary for the purposes of this discussion)

Now, suppose that $T:V \to W$ is a linear map, with $V = \bigoplus_{i=1}^n V_i$, $W = \bigoplus_{i=1}^m W_i$. We see that for any $j$, $T(v \otimes e_j)$ is a linear map. With that established, we see that there must exist maps $T_{1j},\dots,T_{nj}$ such that
$$
T(v \otimes e_j) = (T_{1j}(v),T_{2j}(v),\dots,T_{mj}(v)).
$$
With the maps $T_{ij}$ defined in this fashion, we see that, by the definition of linearity, we have
$$
T(v_1,\dots,v_n) = 
\pmatrix{T_{11}(v_1) + \cdots + T_{1n}(v_n)\\
\vdots \\
T_{m1}(v_1) + \cdots + T_{mn}(v_n)} := 
\pmatrix{T_{11} & \cdots & T_{1n}\\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
T_{m1} & \cdots & T_{mn}} \pmatrix{v_1\\ \vdots \\ v_n}.
$$
On the right side above, we have introduced a new notation: we have a matrix whose entries are linear transformation. By performing the indicated "matrix multiplication", we obtain the desired result, namely $T(v_1,\dots,v_n)$. With that in mind, we say that the **block-matrix representation** of $T$ (with respect to the decompositions of $V,W$) is given by
$$
T = \pmatrix{
T_{11} & \cdots & T_{1n}\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
T_{m1} & \cdots & T_{mn}
} = 
\left(
\begin{array}{c|c|c}
T_{11} & \cdots & T_{1n}\\
\hline \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
\hline T_{m1} & \cdots & T_{mn}
\end{array}
\right).
$$
Now, suppose that we have maps $T:V \to W$ and $S: W \to Z$, where $V,W$ are as above and $Z = Z_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus Z_p$. We can now see that for any vector $(v_1,\dots,v_n) \in V$, we have
$$
(S \circ T)(v) = S(Tv) = S \left[ \pmatrix{T_{11} & \cdots & T_{1n}\\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
T_{m1} & \cdots & T_{mn}} \pmatrix{v_1\\ \vdots \\ v_n} \right]\\
= 
\pmatrix{S_{11} & \cdots & S_{1m}\\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
T_{p1} & \cdots & T_{pm}}
\left[ \pmatrix{T_{11} & \cdots & T_{1n}\\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
T_{m1} & \cdots & T_{mn}} \pmatrix{v_1\\ \vdots \\ v_n} \right]
\\ = 
\left[\pmatrix{S_{11} & \cdots & S_{1m}\\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
T_{p1} & \cdots & T_{pm}}
 \pmatrix{T_{11} & \cdots & T_{1n}\\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
T_{m1} & \cdots & T_{mn}} \right] \pmatrix{v_1\\ \vdots \\ v_n},
$$
where we define the product of two block matrices in the "expected way". On the other hand,
$$
(S \circ T)(v) = 
\pmatrix{(S \circ T)_{11} & \cdots & (S \circ T)_{1n}\\ \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
(S \circ T)_{m1} & \cdots & (S \circ T)_{mn}}\pmatrix{v_1\\ \vdots \\ v_n}.
$$
So, it must be the case that multiplying the block-matrix of $S$ and the block-matrix of $T$ gives us the block-matrix of $S \circ T$.

---

For your particular example, $M$ represents a map from $\Bbb R^{k + d} = \Bbb R^k \oplus \Bbb R^d$ to $\Bbb R^n$.  The block-matrix of $M$ is given by $[A\ \ B]$, which is to say that
$$
M \pmatrix{v_1\\v_2} = \pmatrix{A & B} \pmatrix{v_1\\v_2} = Av_1 + Bv_2.
$$
On the other hand, the block matrix of $M'$ is $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}A'\\B'\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, which is to say that for $w \in \Bbb R^n$ we have
$$
M'w = \pmatrix{A'\\B'}w = \pmatrix{A'w\\ B'w}.
$$
With that established, the block matrix of $M' \circ M$ is the product of the block matrices,
$$
M'M = \pmatrix{A'\\B'} \pmatrix{A & B} = \pmatrix{A'A & A'B\\ B'A & B'B}.
$$
Indeed, if you agree with my description of the maps corresponding to $M$ and $M'$, then for $v = (v_1,v_2)$ we have
$$
M'M v = M'(Mv) = M' (Av_1 + Bv_2) = \pmatrix{A'(Av_1 + Bv_2)\\ B'(Av_1 + Bv_2)}\\
= \pmatrix{A'A v_1 + A'B v_2\\ B'A v_1 + B'B v_2}.
$$