# Why does matrix partitioning work?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

I couldn’t find a proof as to why matrix partitioning works for matrix multiplication. Is there any intuitive and even better, a concrete proof of this?

Comment: Please include more context. What is "matrix partitioning"? And how does it relate with matrix multiplication?

Comment: @azif00: I presume that it refers to the fact that block matrices can be multiplied “blockwise”. Anyway, the proof of that is nothing deep, just a straightforward verification using the definition of matrix multiplication.

Comment: @HansLundmark I disagree for the same reason that mechanical verification is not a great way to prove the associativity of matrix multiplication.

Comment: @BenGrossmann: Well, for both $(AB)C$ and $A(BC)$ the $(i,l)$ entry expands to $\sum_j \sum_k a_{ij} b_{jk} c_{kl}$, so the mechanical verification of associativity is as easy as one could ask for. Whether it's “great” or not is of course a matter of taste. I assume that what you mean is that you prefer the conceptual argument that composition of functions is associative? Sure, I can agree with that! If you have a nice similar argument for block multiplication, that would perhaps make a good answer to this question.

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was getting at. And yes, I do have an argument along those lines. I've definitely written something up about that before, but unfortunately I'm not able to find my previous answer, so I guess I'll have to write an answer from scratch

Comment: @Hans The one sentence explanation is this: matrix partitions are "inherited" from decompositions of the linear transformation's domain/codomain.

Comment: @BenGrossmann: Yes, that's certainly conceptually more satisfying. On the other hand, even someone who only knows the “mechanics” of how to multiply matrices, but is not comfortable with thinking about vector spaces or linear transformations abstractly, should be able to understand to why block multiplication works simply through the down-to-earth explanation where you follow what happens when you run along the rows of the left factor and the columns of the second factor and pair elements up.

Comment: @HansLundmark I suppose you're right. It might just be the result of my own tastes, but I took "intuitive" in the question to mean "conceptual" as opposed to "mechanical".

Comment: @BenGrossmann: Fair enough! But one may also interpret “concrete” in the question to mean “mechanical”... :-)

Comment: @Maxim You might find my [explanation here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3747580/81360) to be helfpul

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's the way I like to think about matrix partitioning. In brief, matrices inherit their "partitioning" from decompositions of the domain and codomain of the linear transformation. The following can be formalized into a more general statement and proof, but for concreteness and ease of writing I'll stick to a specific example.

Let's say that we're looking at $5 \times 6$ matrices. That is, we're looking at a matrix like
$$
A = \pmatrix{
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,5} & a_{1,6}\\ 
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} & a_{2,5} & a_{2,6}\\ 
a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} & a_{3,5} & a_{3,6}\\ 
a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,5} & a_{4,6}\\ 
a_{5,1} & a_{5,2} & a_{5,3} & a_{5,4} & a_{5,5} & a_{5,6}}.
$$
We want to break this matrix into "pieces", and the way that we're going to do this is by breaking the domain $\Bbb R^6$ and codomain $\Bbb R^5$ into pieces. Suppose that we decompose $\Bbb R^6$ into the direct sum $\Bbb R^6 = \Bbb R \oplus \Bbb R^2 \oplus \Bbb R^3$. In other words, instead of thinking of input vectors as a "list of numbers" $\mathbf x = (x_1,\dots,x_6)^T$, we'd rather think of them as a "list of vectors"
$$
x = 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\
\hline
x_2\\
x_3\\
\hline
x_4\\
x_5\\
x_6
\end{array}
\right) = 
\pmatrix{\mathbf x_1\\ \mathbf x_2 \\ \mathbf x_3}, \quad \mathbf x_1 \in \Bbb R^1, \mathbf x_2 \in \Bbb R^2, \mathbf x_3 \in \Bbb R^3.
$$
Similarly, we'll break $\Bbb R^5$ into $\Bbb R^5 = \Bbb R^3 \oplus \Bbb R^2$. That is, we'll write an output vector $y \in \Bbb R^5$ as
$$
y = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
y_1\\
y_2\\
y_3\\
\hline
y_4\\
y_5
\end{array}
\right) = \pmatrix{\mathbf y_1\\ \mathbf y_2} , \quad \mathbf y_1 \in \Bbb R^3 , \mathbf y_2 \in \mathbb R^2.
$$
Now, let's write the equation $\mathbf y = A \mathbf x$ and partition $A$ in a way that "matches" these partitions: the rows are divided into segments of lengths $3$ and $2$ (just like $\mathbf y$), and the columns are divided into segments of lengths $1,2,3$.
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
y_1\\
y_2\\
y_3\\
\hline
y_4\\
y_5
\end{array}
\right) = 
\left(
\begin{array}{c|cc|ccc}
a_{1,1} & a_{1,2} & a_{1,3} & a_{1,4} & a_{1,5} & a_{1,6}\\ 
a_{2,1} & a_{2,2} & a_{2,3} & a_{2,4} & a_{2,5} & a_{2,6}\\ 
a_{3,1} & a_{3,2} & a_{3,3} & a_{3,4} & a_{3,5} & a_{3,6}\\ 
\hline
a_{4,1} & a_{4,2} & a_{4,3} & a_{4,4} & a_{4,5} & a_{4,6}\\ 
a_{5,1} & a_{5,2} & a_{5,3} & a_{5,4} & a_{5,5} & a_{5,6}
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x_1\\
\hline
x_2\\
x_3\\
\hline
x_4\\
x_5\\
x_6
\end{array}
\right)
$$
Notice that the resulting pieces of the matrix are broken up according to which pieces of $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$ they interact with during matrix-multiplication. For example, the first "block-row" of the partitioned matrix $A$ only affects $\mathbf y_1$, and the second "block-column" only interacts with $\mathbf x_2$. In fact, we can say something stronger: rewrite the matrix $A$ as the "block matrix"
$$
A = \pmatrix{
A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13}\\
A_{21} & A_{22} & A_{23}}.
$$
So, for example, $A_{21} = (a_{4,1},a_{5,1})^T$. The following equations hold:
$$
\mathbf y_1 = A_{11} \mathbf x_1 + A_{12} \mathbf x_2 + A_{13} \mathbf x_3\\
\mathbf y_2 = A_{21} \mathbf x_1 + A_{22} \mathbf x_2 + A_{23} \mathbf x_3.
$$
In other words, if we "pretend" that each of the $\mathbf y_i, \mathbf x_j, A_{ij}$ are numbers, then the following "formal" matrix-product yields the correct result:
$$
\pmatrix{\mathbf y_1\\ \mathbf y_2} = 
\pmatrix{
A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13}\\
A_{21} & A_{22} & A_{23}}
\pmatrix{\mathbf x_1\\ \mathbf x_2\\ \mathbf x_3} = 
\pmatrix{
A_{11} \mathbf x_1 + A_{12} \mathbf x_2 + A_{13} \mathbf x_3\\
A_{21} \mathbf x_1 + A_{22} \mathbf x_2 + A_{23} \mathbf x_3}.
$$

---

The more general version of block-matrix multiplication comes in when another transformation is brought into play. Suppose that we want to compute the product $BA$ where $B$ is $7 \times 5$. For consistency's sake, $\Bbb R^5$ will stay broken up the same way, but the codomain of $\Bbb R^7$ will be broken up into $\Bbb R^4 \oplus \Bbb R^3$. Just like last time, we can write
$$
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
z_1\\
z_2\\
z_3\\
z_4\\
\hline
z_5\\
z_6\\
z_7
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{ccc|cc}
b_{1,1} & b_{1,2} & b_{1,3} & b_{1,4} & b_{1,5}\\ 
b_{2,1} & b_{2,2} & b_{2,3} & b_{2,4} & b_{2,5}\\ 
b_{3,1} & b_{3,2} & b_{3,3} & b_{3,4} & b_{3,5}\\ 
b_{4,1} & b_{4,2} & b_{4,3} & b_{4,4} & b_{4,5}\\ 
\hline
b_{5,1} & b_{5,2} & b_{5,3} & b_{5,4} & b_{5,5}\\ 
b_{6,1} & b_{6,2} & b_{6,3} & b_{6,4} & b_{6,5}\\ 
b_{7,1} & b_{7,2} & b_{7,3} & b_{7,4} & b_{7,5}
\end{array}
\right)
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
y_1\\
y_2\\
y_3\\
\hline
y_4\\
y_5
\end{array}
\right).
$$
However, if we write $\mathbf y = A\mathbf x$, then all together this becomes
$$
\pmatrix{\mathbf z_1 \\ \mathbf z_2} = 
\pmatrix{B_{11} & B_{12}\\B_{21} & B_{22}}\pmatrix{A_{11} & A_{12} & A_{13}\\
A_{21} & A_{22} & A_{23}} \pmatrix{\mathbf x_1 \\ \mathbf x_2 \\ \mathbf x_3}.
$$
On the other hand, if $C = BA$, then we can also partition the matrix $C$ to get that
$$
\pmatrix{\mathbf z_1 \\ \mathbf z_2} = 
\pmatrix{C_{11} & C_{12} & C_{13}\\
C_{21} & C_{22} & C_{23}} \pmatrix{\mathbf x_1 \\ \mathbf x_2 \\ \mathbf x_3}.
$$
What comes out as a result is that the partitioned matrix $C$ is the the result of applying "block-matrix multiplication" to $B$ and $A$. That is, we have
$$
C_{ij} = B_{i1}A_{1j} + B_{i2}A_{2j}, \quad i = 1,2, \quad j = 1,2,3.
$$
Importantly, what makes the partitioned multiplication work (for instance, what makes it so that each of the products in the equation above are between compatible matrix shapes) is the fact that the intermediate space $\Bbb R^5$ is broken up in the same way relative to both transformations. For example, $\mathbf y_2$ is only affected by the second block-row of $A$ and only interacts with the second block-column of $B$.

Comment: Exactly what I would have said.  As another way of putting it, you can think of block matrices as being related to $\mathcal{L}(\bigoplus_{i=1}^n V_i, \bigoplus_{j=1}^m W_j) \simeq \bigoplus_{i=1}^n \bigoplus_{j=1}^m \mathcal{L}(V_i, W_j)$ and putting the linear transformation in $\mathcal{L}(V_i, W_j)$ into the $ij$ position of a matrix; and then compositions behave exactly the same way, just with compositions in place of matrix multiplications.  (And then, this generalizes to morphisms of abelian groups or $R$-modules also, and I've even seen this notation used for non-free modules.)